# Reading text file with blanks spaces, values, brackets and special characters

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a csv document that I can read to extrapolate columns, which are of the format:

```
'           46.0213(3)      ', '           101.2           ', '           105.8(4)        ', '           --        ', '           117.2  or 22.25  ', '           132.18900       ', '           --        ', '           172.7(6)'
```

where:

1. Blank spaces should be stripped off when I am going to consider the number, that is the `int()` of the list element;
2. the number in brackets at the end of each elements refers to the error (last digit for that value). This has to be taken and processed separately;
3. The value `--` means that no value is known for that case. Probably a `NaN` should be attributed in this case;
4. The first of the two values in case the string element is `x or y`

How do I deal with all those specific requests? I do not need a code for everything, but just a "code of conduct" and some suggestions to find out what is the best approach here.

This is the code I use to read the text file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin python

import os, re, glob, csv

with open('data.txt', 'r') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',', quotechar='(')
    column_I_want = list(zip(*reader))[4]

print column_I_want
```

EDIT: This is a sort of desired output:

```
print values, error
# [ 46.0213, 101.2, 105.8, NaN, 117.2, 132.18900, NaN, 172.7], [0.3, Nan, 0.4, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.6]
```

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: Any clarification for the case with ' 117.2  o 22.25 '? whats the desired result

Comment: @S.Davis, you are right, thank you for pointing that out. That would be the first of the two values. I will edit my question.

Comment: can it be any of the options: 'num', 'num(num2)', 'num or num2'?

Answer (score 1):

1) this removes leading and trailing whitespace

```
string.strip()
```

2, 3, 4)

```
string.strip()
if "--" in string:
    # assign NaN
    pass
elif "or" in string:
    first = float(string.split()[0])
elif "(" in string:
    string.replace('(', ')')
    tok = string.split(')')
    first, second = float(tok[0]), float(tok[1])
else:
    first = float(string)
```

Comment: Can you comment a bit more on this? 
What is the result of `string.strip()`? Is `string` the list or one single value?

Comment: string would be each individual string from the list. string.strip() removes all leading and trailing whitespace from a string, so '           46.0213(3)      ' would become '46.0213(3)'

Comment: @S.Davis Please don't add such information just in the comments, but also added them to your answer. Comments may get deleted.

Comment: What about the other lines? What if a string does not have a final `()`? Does your code apply in that case too?

Comment: Sorry again, why `first, second = int(tok[0]), int(tok[1])`? Is this supposed to deal with `integer` numbers? There is no single integer in my example.

Comment: The error obtained in the way you suggest does not represent the last digit on the value considered. If the value in the string is `46.0213(3)`, your method returns an error of `3`, while it should be `0.0003`.